# Places to view the Danube at Djerdap close to the main road

Tags: serbia, danube

We are going to Serbia in October, and would really like to visit Djerdap national park to get some of those incredible views of the Danube. Unfortunately, we aren't currently able to hike and can go a maximum of a few hundred meters from the car. Not in a wheelchair or anything like that though.

What are some good spots to view the river that fit these criteria?

I understand that the best views are on the eastern side of the park, but especially interesting are places closer to Golubac, if there are any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few years ago I went from Romania to Serbia across the Iron Gates dam border crossing
and followed the road 34 at the right bank of the Danube to Golubac.

Although I don't remember exact positions I remember that along this route (ca. 100km) there were
several points where you have a great view of the Danube gorge right from the road and
several places where you can stop and have an even better view without walking more than 50 steps.

If you zoom in at road 34 at Google Maps you find some of them marked as parking places or scenic points
(e.g. "Gravel Parking Vidikovac" or the one at the northern most point marked "Scenic View").

I recommend going from east to west, so you have the Danube on the same side as you are
driving and can better look ahead to find a good spot and you don't have to cross the road.

Following pictures were taken at those places very close at the road:

[image]

[image]

[image]